# Set the column collate directly from the django model field CharField

Tags: django, django-models

My tables default collate are `utf8mb4_general_ci` but sometimes I need only few columns to be `utf8_general_ci`.

Is there a library or a workaround to set the db columns collate directly from the model fields like this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, collate='utf8_general_ci')
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a workaround, setting the collation for a `CharField` is supported since Django 3.2 by using the [`db_collation` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.db_collation):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, db_collation='utf8_general_ci')
```